# Bash Script: Changing file permissions recursively

Tags: bash, recursion, file-permissions

I need a Bash script that changes the file permissions of all files in a directory and all subdirectories. It should behave like this:

```
for each file in directory (and subdirectories)
   if i am the owner of the file
      if it is a directory
         chmod 770 file
      else
         chmod 660 file
```

I guess it's not a difficult task but I am not very experienced in Bash scripts. Your help is appreciated! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with two invocations of the `find` command, with the `-user` option to filter by user, and the `-type` option to filter by filetype:

```
find . -user "$USER" -type d -exec echo chmod 770 {} +
find . -user "$USER" -not -type d -exec echo chmod 660 {} +
```

Remove `echo` after testing, to actually change the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

`find` is helpful here: it recursively finds files and/or directories that meet particular criteria (in this case, the owner). The other trick is to use the `X` (rather than `x`) flag for `chmod`, which makes directories executable but not regular files. Putting that together via `xargs`:

```
find . -user $(whoami) | xargs chmod ug=Xo=
```

I didn't test this and it's probably slightly wrong. I recommend testing it first :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `find`:

```
find topdirectory -user "$USER" \( -type f -exec chmod 660 {} + \) -o \( -type f -exec chmod 770 {} + \)
```